# Link on Developer Story Page returns 404 error

Tags: bug, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

The "Get your Skill IQ" link on my Developer Story Page is returning a 404 error.

Clicking here

[image]

Gives

[image]

I'm using Firefox 63.0.3 if it makes any difference. Am I the only one with this issue?